# Expiration of refresh tokens Microsoft.Owin

Tags: .net, oauth, owin

I create my refresh token like this:

```
public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
{   
    var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

    context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedAtUtc;
    //context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);

    // Persist created token

    context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
}
```

Is it correct that if i comment `//context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc =` line, my created refresh token would never expire (until i remove it/make deleted)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/24aa43641adac57cb5bd523b77bdc0ced9f0455d/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs#L424-L427) refresh token's `Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc` has access token's expiration time.

<strike>If you'd like to have refresh tokens without expiration, you need to set `ExpiresUtc` with `null` in your refresh token's provider creating method:</strike>

```
context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedAtUtc;
context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = null;
```

**Update:**

[You can't](https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/24aa43641adac57cb5bd523b77bdc0ced9f0455d/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs#L627-L633) have refresh token's without expiration time. Otherwise you'll get `{ "error": "invalid_grant" }`.